# Can I see AWS Service Quota current value? For example total EC2 instances running vs. the set quota value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-service-quotas

I'd like to call the AWS API (possibly using `boto3`) and see the difference between an actual value in production and a Service Quota maxmimum value.

For example there is a Service Quota called "Auto Scaling groups per region" with the value 500, and I can call the Service Quota API with its Quota Code and get that value.

But I might only be running 20 of them in reality, can I compare those numbers?

So I can see if I'm reaching the limit.